# How to consume Rest API Firebase data in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, rest, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database in firebase, and I want to consume this data, and save it to a variable of my object, however I am not understanding how to do this. I have read the Firebase documentation but nothing.

So far I've only got this

```
let guia = firebase.child("guias_administracao")
guia.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

print(snapshot.value as Any)
for item in snapshot.children{
    let g = GuiaAdmModel(
        link: (item as! String),
        nome: (item as! String),
        videoLink: (item as! String)
    )
    self.listGuiaAdm.append(g)
}
```

When I run, this error returns me

```
Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x600000246db0>(
<null>,
{
    link = "guia_administracao/MERCK_GUIA_UTILIZACAO_DIGITAL_fertilidade_2016_09_22_Cetrotide.pdf";
    nome = Cetrotide;
    videoLink = "//player.vimeo.com/video/183506335?color=ff0179&byline=0&portrait=0";
},
{
    link = "guia_administracao/MERCK_GUIA_UTILIZACAO_DIGITAL_fertilidade_2016_09_22_Crinone.pdf";
    nome = Crinone;
    videoLink = "";
},
{
    link = "guia_administracao/MERCK_GUIA_UTILIZACAO_DIGITAL_fertilidade_2016_09_22_Gonalf.pdf";
    nome = Gonalf;
    videoLink = "";
},
{
    link = "gs://fertility-b4db3.appspot.com/guia_administracao/Ovidrel.pdf";
    nome = Ovidrel;
    videoLink = "";
}
)
)
Could not cast value of type 'FIRDataSnapshot' (0x1061f7260) to 'NSString' (0x1079fdc60).
```

Please help me
Some example or tutorial would help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for you assuming you have your model set up properly, if not, change the init to accept snap.key as the key, and snap.value as the second parameter (as a Dict.)

```
guia.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
    for snap in snapshot {
        if let gDict = snap.value as ? Dictionary < String, AnyObject > {
                let g = GuiAdmModel(
                    link: gDict["link"],
                    nome: gDict["nome"],
                    videoLink: gDict["videoLink"]
                )
                self.listGuiaAdm.append(g)
        }
    }
}
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just needed to make small changes that xcode implied, it was like this ...
`for snap in snapshot {
        if let gDict = snap.value as? Dictionary < String, AnyObject > {
                let g = GuiaAdmModel(
                            link: gDict["link"] as! String,
                            nome: gDict["nome"] as! String,
                            videoLink: gDict["videoLink"] as! String
                )
                self.listGuiaAdm.append(g)
                self.tableGuiaAdm.reloadData()
        }
    }`

Comment: Happy to be of service @Ghost . If you found my suggestion helpful, please consider marking it as the answer. I'm relatively new here and the reputation points would mean a lot.